# Splitting large dataframe when there is a jump in timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, split

I have a large dataframe with datetime as indeces and different sensors as columns.
The sensors measure different quantities at a sampling frequency of 1 second

```
                         sensor1  sensor2   sensor3 
timestamp
2017-12-03 16:13:01        20        4465     156      
2017-12-03 16:13:02        20        4466     158
2017-12-03 16:13:03        20        4466     158
.
.
2017-12-03 16:45:05        30        4468     178
2017-12-03 16:45:06        30        4468     178     <I want to split the dataframe at jumps in
2017-12-03 18:00:00        20        4141      89     time like here.
2017-12-03 18:00:01        22        4321      90
2017-12-03 18:00:02        22        4321      90
```

I want to split the large dataframe into smaller dataframes whenever a jump in time is located. Or in other words I would like to split the dataframe whenever the next timestep is larger than one second later.

Comment: split as in create a `list` of dataframes?  like `[df1, df2, df3]`?

Comment: Yes exactly what i had in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach would be to create a further column with a group counter

```
df['groups'] = (df.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds > 1).cumsum()

#                      sensor1  sensor2  sensor3  groups
# timestamp                                             
# 2017-12-03 16:13:01       20     4465      156       0
# 2017-12-03 16:13:02       20     4466      158       0
# 2017-12-03 16:13:03       20     4466      158       0
# 2017-12-03 16:45:05       30     4468      178       1
# 2017-12-03 16:45:06       30     4468      178       1
# 2017-12-03 18:00:00       20     4141       89       2
# 2017-12-03 18:00:01       22     4321       90       2
# 2017-12-03 18:00:02       22     4321       90       2
```

then `groupby` this new column:

```
for ct, data in df.groupby('groups'):
    print(ct, data.drop(columns=['groups']))

# 0                      sensor1  sensor2  sensor3
# timestamp                                     
# 2017-12-03 16:13:01       20     4465      156
# 2017-12-03 16:13:02       20     4466      158
# 2017-12-03 16:13:03       20     4466      158

# 1                      sensor1  sensor2  sensor3
# timestamp                                     
# 2017-12-03 16:45:05       30     4468      178
# 2017-12-03 16:45:06       30     4468      178

# 2                      sensor1  sensor2  sensor3
# timestamp                                     
# 2017-12-03 18:00:00       20     4141       89
# 2017-12-03 18:00:01       22     4321       90
# 2017-12-03 18:00:02       22     4321       90
```